# Problema com consulta SQL

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta mas que me retorne os valores selecionados numa `select` e não consigo porque me retorna todos os valores inseridos. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="consultar_documento.php">
Selecionar Tipo de Documento
<select name="COMBO" id="COMBO">
<option></option>
<?php    
$botao   = $_REQUEST['BT'];
$server  = 'localhost';
$DBName  = 'arquivo';
$senha   = '';
$usuario = 'root';

$con12=mysql_connect($server,$usuario,$senha);
if($con12) {
  $selecionar=mysql_select_db($DBName,$con12);
  if($selecionar) {
    $consulta="SELECT descricao FROM tipo_de_documento";
    $resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$con12);

    while ($Reg=mysql_fetch_row($resultado)) {
      foreach ($Reg as $Val) {
        echo "<option>$Val</option>";
      }
    }

    mysql_close($con12);
  }
}
?>  

</select> 
<input type="submit" name="BT" id="BT" value="Consultar" />

</form> 

<?php 
$botao=$_REQUEST['BT'];
$server='localhost';
$DBName='arquivo';
$senha='';
$usuario='root';

$con12 = mysql_connect($server,$usuario,$senha);   
if($con12) {
  $selecionar=mysql_select_db($DBName,$con12);
  if($selecionar) {
    if($botao=='Consultar') {
      if ((isset($_POST['interno'])) && (!empty($_POST['externo']))) {
        $consulta = "SELECT tipo_de_documento.id_tipodocumento, tipo_de_documento.descricao, 
        tipo_de_documento.Data_entrada, tipo_de_documento.Data_saida, tipo_de_documento.UEO, 
        documento.assunto, documento.n_doc, documento.n_folhas, documento.n_exemplares, 
        documento.iddocumento, tipo_de_documento.id_tipodocumento 
        FROM documento, tipo_de_documento 
        WHERE tipo_de_documento.descricao = '".$_POST['tipo_de_documento']."'";
      }

      $resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$con12);

      echo "<table border='1' align='center' width='900' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'> ";
      echo "<tr>"; 
      echo "<table border='1' align='center' width='900' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'> ";  
      echo "<tr>"; 
      echo "<th colspan='9'>";
      echo 'documento';echo $COMBO;
      echo "</th>"; 
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'IDENTIFICADOR DE DOCUMENTO';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'DESCRICAO';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'DATA_ENTRADA';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'DATA_SAIDA';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'UEO';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'ASSUNTO';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'NUMERO DO DOCUMENTO';
      echo "</th>"; 
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'NUMERO DE FOLHAS';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";
      echo 'NUMERO DE EXEMPLARES';
      echo "</th>";
      echo "<th>";


      echo mysql_num_rows($resultado) or die ("".mysql_error ());

      while ($Reg=mysql_fetch_row($resultado)) {
        echo "<tr>";

        foreach ($Reg as $Val) {
          echo "<td>$Val</td> ";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";

      mysql_close($con12);
    }
  }
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Não deveria ter um `where` em algum lugar?

Comment: [Veja esse assunto](https://elias.praciano.com/2015/04/como-filtrar-resultados-com-a-clausula-where-no-mysql/)

Comment: Qual o método que você usa no `<form>` e qual o `name` do `<select>`?

Comment: no form uso o metodo post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu SQL deveria ficar assim:

```
if ((isset($_POST['tipo_de_documento'])) && (!empty($_POST['tipo_de_documento']))) {
    $consulta = "SELECT tipo_de_documento.id_tipodocumento, tipo_de_documento.descricao, 
    tipo_de_documento.Data_entrada, tipo_de_documento.Data_saida, tipo_de_documento.UEO, 
    documento.assunto, documento.n_doc, documento.n_folhas, documento.n_exemplares, 
    documento.iddocumento, tipo_de_documento.id_tipodocumento 
    FROM documento, tipo_de_documento 
    WHERE tipo_de_documento.descricao = '".$_POST['tipo_de_documento']."'";
}
```

Onde está `$_POST['tipo_de_documento']` altere `tipo_de_documento` para o `name` que está no `<select>`.

Comment: obrigada,so que quando eu altero o meu codigo aparece erro de sintaxe nessa linha aqui if (isset($_POST['tipo_de_documento']) && (!empty($_POST['tipo_de_documento'])) { e não estou sabendo como corrigir...mas uma ajuda ai por favor

Comment: Corrigi o código. Faltaram alguns parênteses. Tente de novo.

Comment: olá tentei de novo com o código corrigido e agora a consulta não retorna nem um valor

Comment: Tem como você colocar o código completo no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: enviei para ti  o codigo completo

Comment: Enviou por onde?

Comment: ups não consigo enviar posso postar mesmo aqui?

Comment: Edita sua pergunta colocando o código todo.

Comment: Cara, eu te falei pra mudar `$_POST['tipo_de_documento']` trocando o `tipo_de_documento` pelo nome do seu `select`. O nome do seu `select` não é `tipo_de_documento` é `COMBO`. vai ficar `$_POST['COMBO']`

Comment: alterei está a funcionar corretamente,muito obrigada principalmente pela paciencia.Você salvou o meu dia e muitos dias fustrados.Obrigada você é de maisss

Comment: Clica no check do lado da minha resposta pra marcar como aceita.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, neste caso seu SELECT vai trazer tudo mesmo, se você quer um determinado valor é preciso inserir o WHERE na variavel $consulta, você precisa linkar as duas tabelas dentro da clausula WHERE, você repete o ID do tipo de documento na mas tabela de tipo de documento duas vezes, creio que uma delas deveria ser a coluna ID_TIPODOCUMENTO da tabela 'documento', certo ?
Tendo essa chave estrangeira você precisará linkar ela na clausula where e separar por qualquer outra condição que desejar seguidas pelo AND: Exemplo:

```
FROM DOCUMENTO, TIPO_DE_DOCUMENTO
WHERE DOCUMENTO.ID_TIPODOCUMENTO = TIPO_DE_DOCUMENTO.ID_TIPODOCUMENTO
AND DOCUMENTO.ASSUNTO = 'terça-feira';
```

Comment: estou fazendo essa consulta porque na tabela existem 3 tipos de documentos interno,externo e hibrido,o que eu quero é que quando faço um clique em um deles me mostra todos os dados só do documento selecionado.O que não acontece porque a consulta me mostra os dados dos 3 tipos de documentos de uma so vez...